# What could cause a BackgroundWorker to fail without throwing an Exception?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, backgroundworker, cancellation

I'm trying to debug a WPF application that consistently crashes on one particular machine. We never encountered the crash in our testing but we're worried this could be happening to customers as well.

The crash occurs while a BackgroundWorker is running.

```
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(argument);
```

I'd know if an Exception was thrown because the RunWorkerCompleted event handler would log the Exception in a log file.

```
    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Logger.LogMessage(e.Error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I know approximately where in the DoWork handler the crash is occurring because it's in the middle of a set of file operations, and I can see which files have already been moved after the application is run. My first thought was that it was a usual file operation error such as a permissions issue, but all my testing indicates that an Exception would be thrown and I'd be able to see it. I also checked to see if there's a try/catch block that could be catching the Exception and there isn't.

The failure seems to be at some point during the execution of this loop:

```
        if (Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory))
        {
            var relativeFiles = HelperService.GetRelativeFiles(sourceDirectory);

            foreach (string relativeFile in relativeFiles)
            {
                string destPath = Path.Combine(basePath, relativeFile);
                string sourcePath = Path.Combine(sourceDirectory, relativeFile);
                HelperService.MoveAndOverwriteFile(sourcePath, destPath);
            }
        }
```

And here is HelperService.MoveAndOverwriteFile:

```
    public static void MoveAndOverwriteFile(string sourcePath, string destPath)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPath));
        File.Delete(destPath);
        File.Move(sourcePath, destPath);
    }
```

I thought maybe something was canceling the BackgroundWorker, but I understand the CancelAsync() method doesn't abort the thread but rather sets the CancellationPending property, meaning CancelAsync() does nothing unless the DoWork handler is designed to respond to it. Is there any .NET functionality that could cancel or abort a BackgroundWorker without me knowing about it?

It's also as though something is forcing the application to shut down, but I haven't found anything that would do that. Could there be some .NET error that's so drastic that it aborts the whole application rather than throwing an Exception? I checked the Windows Event Viewer and there aren't any errors associated with this.

Should I suspect a hardware failure perhaps?

I know BackgroundWorker isn't really used anymore, but I inherited some old code that uses a lot of BackgroundWorkers. I'll probably use async/await in future versions. But I still want to figure this out.

Comment: Have you tried enabling all exceptions in visual studio?

Comment: @Marker Would that affect the compiled exe or just the debugger?

Comment: Just the debugger

Comment: @Marker How would that help? I can't reproduce the problem on my dev machine.